# Alter CSS after it is created by nth-child?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a table with alternated-color rows generated by nth-class. I want to be able to click them to change the background color by changing its class. This works without nth-child, but I need to have them alternate color. This changes the font color but does not override the nth-child background-color.

Row CSS:

```
#messageLogTable tr:nth-child(odd):not([class=highlightNewInfoRow]):not([class=tableHeader]):not([class=clickedRow]) {
background-color:#DEDDCD;
}
#messageLogTable tr:nth-child(even):not([class=highlightNewInfoRow]):not([class=clickedRow]) {
background-color:#D0CFB9;
}
```

I try to alter it with jQuery:

```
$('#'+entryId).removeClass('highlightClickableRow');
$('#'+entryId).addClass('clickedRow');
```

.clickedRow CSS:

```
.clickedRow {
background-color:#446121;
color:white;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ":not([class=highlightNewInfoRow])" when you can just use ":not(.highlightNewInfoRow)"? No need to call it via attribute.

Comment: `:nth-child()` is not `:nth-class()`. There is no such `:nth-class()` selector, and `:nth-child()` doesn't filter by classes (or anything else really).

Comment: Right. I understand. But I was wondering how to override the background-color set by the nth-child function. Apparently, setting a class did not do it. So, I chose to override the background-color with a background. If there's another way I would like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery API documentation contains almost this exact example at http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/.

Comment: Well, I appreciate the link but I must be missing something. I see nothing there about adding style after it has been added by nth-child? Are you suggesting to use jQuery:even instead of nth-child? I will investigate that and see if I can make that easier. However, I'm still curious about how to apply the correct change in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the CSS of the class I add to be a background: -webkit-linear-gradient that doesn't change color. It works fine.